# Pinescript not respecting SL levels

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm playing around with Pinescript and am attempting to create a strategy, with SL and TP levels based on ATR values on bar close when the strategy.entry is executed. I currently have my SL formula set to:

```
atr = ta.atr(14)
longSL = close - (input.float(Title = "Long SL ATR Multiplier", defval = 6.0, step = 0.1) * atr)
```

From my understanding, this returns a price value that I want to set as my SL.
To ensure that the strategy was in fact exiting at the correct price or not, I created a separate indicator with the same code that just prints the value of my longSL overlayed onto my charts. However, I noticed that the exits taken by the strategy were not matched up to the longSL levels on close of the entry bar. This image shows my issue:[red line indicates what should be the SL level according to the ATR calculation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy3AS.png)  The price breaks through the SL multiple times without actually closing the order.

my code for strategy entry/exit is:

```
if (longCondition)
        strategy.entry("Long Entry", strategy.long, qty = longPositionSize, comment="Long Entry")
        strategy.exit("Long Exit", stop = longSL, comment = "Long Exit")
```

If it's relevant, pyramiding is disabled on the current script.

I genuinely do not know what is going wrong here. Because my indicator plots the same exact value that should be returned by longSL, and I use that value in my strategy.exit, I do not know why it doesn't sell even if price reaches that level.

Does anyone know what exactly I'm doing wrong here? Any insight would be fantastic.

Edit: added stripped down code.

```
// Risk Management
length = input(14)
atr = ta.atr(length)

lslATR = (input(title = "Long SL ATR multiplier", defval = 4), *atr)
ltpATR =  (input(title = "Long TP ATR multiplier", defval = 4.8), *atr)
sslATR = (input(title = "Short SL ATR multiplier", defval = 5.4), *atr)
stpATR = (input(title = "Short TP ATR multiplier", defval = 4.1), *atr)

entryPrice = close

lsl =  entryPrice - lslATR
ltp = entryPrice + ltpATR
ssl = entryPrice + sslATR
stp = entryPrice - stpATR


if (not na(rsi))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long Entry", strategy.long, qty = 200))
    strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long Entry", stop = lsl, limit = ltp)
    
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short Entry", strategy.short, qty = 200))
    strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Short Entry", stop = ssl, limit = 
    stp)
```

Comment: Do you want your SL to be fixed or trailing? Could you please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There are two possible issues that I see but need to see a minimal example.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm quite new to Pinescript and coding in general, so please excuse any inaccuracies or misunderstandings. From my understanding, a minimal, reproducible example would look like the code in this image:
https://imgur.com/a/XtCTyUb

(I apologize if it is against the norm to post links on Stackoverflow, this is my first post.)

Although it's likely not crucial to the setting of the stop loss, I left in my position sizing calculation just in case it has an effect on risk management. Any clarity on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't add your code as an image. Instead, edit your question and add it there.

Comment: @vitruvius Done. Sorry for the formatting issues. If there are any other pieces of code you need (strategy conditions or whatnot) to piece together what's going wrong, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want a fixed SL?

Comment: @vitruvius Apologies for the late response. After doing a lot of searching, I figured out a way to carry over the value of my SL into my order by using changes in strategy.position_size values. Now all my exits correspond to the exact levels my SLs are set at, so I think I'm all good for help. I appreciate your time and effort to respond!